# VirtualBox cannot be started, removed or reinstalled

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 which recently stopped working, maybe due to recent updates. My kernel version is 4.15.0-48.

When I try to type "virtualbox -v" in the command line, it's just loading and nothing happens. When I try to start virtualbox via "sudo virtualbox", again nothing happens.

Could it be that virtualbox is not compatible with recent updates so I have to rollback to an older kernel version?

`dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` # show installed VB software

```
ii  virtualbox                     5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

**Update:**

I did all of these steps...

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox

dkms status # showed four different types of software which I then removed with the following command...

sudo dkms remove virtualbox/5.1.38 --all # remove

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms # uninstall other VB softwares

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-qt # uninstall other VB softwares

sudo apt-get update # update software database

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0 # install newer version

The result is that when I try to start virtualbox 6 with sudo virtualbox in the terminal, again nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

**Another Update:**

```
dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii

ii  virtualbox-6.0                 6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~xenial   amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox

dkms status virtualbox-6.0 # nothing

ls -al /boot

drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Mai 24 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Mai 20 13:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217004 Mär 15 19:40 config-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 Apr  5 15:27 config-4.15.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 Mai  8 22:14 config-4.15.0-50-generic
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Mai 20 13:49 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54509169 Mai  8 10:46 initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55180745 Mai 20 13:37 initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55477719 Mai 24 12:53 initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4049889 Mär 15 19:40 System.map-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4051368 Apr  5 15:27 System.map-4.15.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4052501 Mai  8 22:14 System.map-4.15.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8130328 Mär 18 15:23 vmlinuz-4.15.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8141400 Apr  8 10:53 vmlinuz-4.15.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8141336 Mai 14 20:09 vmlinuz-4.15.0-50-generic
```

Comment: what updates are we talking here?

Comment: You may need to upgrade Virtualbox, not downgrade the kernel.

Comment: status please...

Comment: On the virtualbox website it says that Virtualbox 5.1.38 is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. but is no longer supported, but Virtualbox 5.1.x is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

**Update Virtualbox like so...**

In `terminal`...

`dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` # show installed VB software

```
ii  virtualbox                     5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

`sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` # uninstall VB 5.1

`dkms status` # note the name of the virtualbox software

**Note**: with the next command, you **may** need to change "virtualbox-dkms" to the name found with the `dkms status` command... let me know if you have any problem...

`sudo dkms remove virtualbox-dkms/5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 --all` # remove dkms driver

`sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms` # uninstall other VB softwares

`sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-qt` # uninstall other VB softwares

`sudo apt-get update` # update software database

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0` # install newer version

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've updated my initial question as I did all of these steps, but still virtualbox doesn't start, it's just loading until I close the terminal window.

Comment: @MiriamAlida ok, lets revisit some earlier commands so that I can see where we are. Edit your question with the current output of `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` and `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @Mrmld status please

Comment: @Mrmld Great news! Please remember to accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!